# How to populate parameters values present in rows of one dataframe(df1) to dataframe(df2) under same parameter field in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

New to R, please guide !

Dataframe1 contain:

```
df1
    Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5 
    A=5   C=1   E=5  F=4  G=2  --Row1 
    A=6   B=3   D=6  E=4  F=4  --Row2 
    B=2   C=3   D=3  E=3  F=7  --Row3
```

Dataframe2 contain one row with each parameters as field names:
df2 = A B C D E F  g .....'n'

Example Output (if values not found the null to be printed):

```
df2:
A  B  C  D   E   F   G
5     1      5   4   2
6  3     6   4   4
   2  3  3   3   7
```

How to populate values of each parameter from df1 to df2 under same parameter which are present in first row as fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a row number column (`rownames_to_column`), `gather` into 'long' format, `separate` the 'val' column into two (by splitting at `=`- automatically picked up) and then `spread` into 'wide' format.  By default, the elements that are missing are filled by `NA`.  There is also a `fill` argument to change it to the desired fill value

```
library(tidyverse)
res <- df1 %>%
        rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
        gather(key, val, -rn) %>% 
        separate(val, into = c('val1', 'val2')) %>%
        select(-key) %>%
        spread(val1, val2) %>%
        select(-rn)
res
#     A    B    C    D E F    G
#1    5 <NA>    1 <NA> 5 4    2
#2    6    3 <NA>    6 4 4 <NA>
#3 <NA>    2    3    3 3 7 <NA>
```

If there is a second dataset containing some values and want to replace the non-NA elements in 'df2'

```
df2[!is.na(df2)] <-  res[!is.na(df2)][names(df2)]
```

---

Or another option is `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1)[, tstrsplit(unlist(.SD), "="), .(grp = 1:nrow(df1))
               ], grp ~ V1, value.var = 'V2')[, grp := NULL][]
#    A  B  C  D E F  G
#1:  5 NA  1 NA 5 4  2
#2:  6  3 NA  6 4 4 NA
#3: NA  2  3  3 3 7 NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A=5", "A=6", "B=2"), Col2 = c("C=1", 
"B=3", "C=3"), Col3 = c("E=5", "D=6", "D=3"), Col4 = c("F=4", 
"E=4", "E=3"), Col5 = c("G=2", "F=4", "F=7")), .Names = c("Col1", 
"Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: I have values from both dataframes, i.e, df1 & df2. df1 contains all the parameters and their values in multiple cols. df2 contains only parameter names in first field. Now I have to populate values of df1 to df2 under same parameters reading each rows of df1 (as shown in example). Can you pls explain your second clarification/solution as posted above ?

Comment: @rjn_bnf  You can create the 'df2' directly from 'df1' that is what i showed.  In the 2nd dataset you showed, it is exactly similar to the output got from reshaping 'df1'.  So, it is not clear about the logic

Comment: Can't it be possible to map the values of same parameters from df1 to df2 ?

Comment: @rjn_bnf  I updated the post.  Please check.  Based on your example, it is not making much logic to change it as it is already similar

Comment: I tried to implement this syntax but unable to deploy it properly. Hence, concluding with a error

Comment: @rjn_bnf what is the error and also please show the `dput` of 'df2'

Comment: I am working with VCF data where I'm parsing INFO field parameters. I have parsed the parameters and now, I have to place their values (present in df1) under each fields (df2). Your clarifications are well eligible to implement in my script but, the functions that I have used they are giving errors. Is there any place of communicate where I can share few snapshots for your reference ?

Comment: @rjn_bnf  Are these regular data.frame objects?  From your description, it may not be the case.

Comment: No, these are not. These are the output of samples (vcf files). It will vary for each and every dataset !

Comment: @rjn_bnf  Okay, that may be the reason.  I thought these as data.frame objects